# Problem converting OpenStreetMap tiles to mbtiles

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, osmium, tippecanoe

I'm trying to convert the OSM tiles from https://download.geofabrik.de/ to .mbtiles.

I'm converting the .pbf to .geojson like:

`osmium export -f geojson europe.osm.pbf -o europe.geojson`

and then the geojson to .mbtiles like:

`tippecanoe --drop-densest-as-needed -o europe.mbtiles europe.geojson -l 4`

I've tried with layers 0, 4, 7 but it always looks like this:
https://i.ibb.co/bdfTC4R/mao.jpg

Not sure what the correct layer is, should it be a number or a string as by default it says it's using layer 0, or the problem is with the previous conversion. Any help would be greatly appreciated!